# Oracle rman backup schedule after a failed level 1 incremental backup

Tags: oracle, database-backups, disaster-recovery, rman

I created rman backup level 0 on monday -> succeeded , level 1 on tuesday -> succeeded
,level 1 on wednessday -> failed

My doubts are
1)after the failed schedule which level (0/1/cumulative) of backup i have to take to make sure my database integrity ?
2)Shall I need to keep the failed schedule data or I can delete ?

Comment: It might depend on what specifically failed, and why. In general, you should be ok just to run another incremental backup as long as you're not missing any archived redo logs. Don't delete the failed backup unless you're sure it doesn't contain any archived redo logs.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. For integrity checking using rman> validate database
Q2. Configure retention policy and have rman clean obsolete backup for you.